# Retrieve column names instead of foreign id in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySql Db named as newtbl which has 2 columns referenced as a foreign keys they are m_id, p_id. I want that instead of these m_id and p_id their names should be displayed.

Query which I wrote is below, but it has errors.

```
select newtbl.*, pa.p_name, m.m_id
from newtbl
left join matches m on newtbl.m_id = m.m_id
left join players pa on newtbl.p_id = pa.p_id
```

Comment: The query is syntactically correct so what error are you getting?

Comment: Why are you selecting `m.m_id`?  You already have it in `newtbl.*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to column an alias name used `as`

```
select newtbl.*, pa.p_name, m.m_id  as 'mmID'
from newtbl 
left join matches m on newtbl.m_id = m.m_id 
left join players pa on newtbl.p_id = pa.p_id
```

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi Fixed it.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' matches m on newtbl.m_id = m.m_id 
left join players pa on newtbl.p_id = pa.p_' at line 3

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi remove comma it was extra

Answer (score 0):

Below is a answer for my question.

```
 select newtbl.u_id, pa.p_name from newtbl left join players pa on newtbl.p_id = pa.p_id
```